# android: How to prevent GridView from getting focus and pass it to parent view?

Tags: android, gridview, focus, onitemclicklistener

I am trying to make this whole view clickable through adapter which holds a few instances of this View.
I am using onitemclicklistener but it won't fire when inside 50 x 50 dp area of child gridview. I really don't know what to do. I tried with setting descendant focusability, setting focusable and/or clickable to false even programmatically setting

```
gridView.isEnabled(false);
```

but nothing seems to work. Everything works fine outside the bounds of gridView but inside nothing works.

P.S. I am aware that this three relativeLayouts are redundant but that is not what am I concerned about.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white" >

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/mega_cell_layout_grid_view"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@android:color/black"

            android:numColumns="3" 
            >
        </GridView> 
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Hi, Have you tried using onInterceptTouchEvent on the GridView? Take a look at the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#onInterceptTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)) for this method

Comment: Hi, thank you, you saved me :) I overrided onInterceptTouchEvent on the main RelativeLayout so it always returns true and it worked like a charm.